# Image alt and title getting messed up when using space

Tags: php, html, css, image

Whenever I use a space in my image alt tag, my whole `<img>` line get's really messed up.

Let's say my img title is `Windows 10`, to be a bit specific for today's news. Let's also say that my img tag is `Windows 10 officially announced`.

What should happen when I insert this in my img tag is:

```
<img src="/windows_10.png" title="Windows 10" alt="Windows 10 officially announced" />
```

But what happens is:

```
<img src="/windows_10.png" title="Windows" 10="" alt="Windows" officially="" announced="">
```

I am retrieving my news from a database, which does `html_entity_decode` before filling the dynamic page. The img tag is stored in the database after doing an `html_entities` function on it. (PHP it's own encoding thingy.)

I really don't get where it's going wrong.

Comment: can you show your full code? you missing quoting or quoting not correctly arranged

Comment: You should show the part of code that actually generates the `img` element and show the actual data as fetched by it from the database, and you should show the actual HTML as generated (what you posted looks like something already parsed by a browser).

Comment: The part that generates the image is html_entity_decode($content); Where content is a row retrieved from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the filtering you are using is exploding (separating) the tag content by spaces, then assigining attr_name,att_value.

On the other hand htmlenitities encode and decode are meant to store and retrieve plaintext from the database, or convert plaintext into html and html text (not code) to plaintext, or escaping html for showing html inside of an html do without rendering it (Check out http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php for examples).

If you just want to store and retrieve html code, there's no need for it.

So you will probably be ok if instead of html_entities encode and decode you just use the html entity `&nbsp;` instead of the  space character and store it like that on the database.

Comment: I feel so stupid now hahaha, thanks mate, it did solve the problem! I will insert it into the system right away, to remove the issue and possibility to forget to add the &nbsp; instead of a space! :)